# Winappdriver is throwing System.InvalidOperationException error

Tags: windows, rpa, winappdriver

```cs
try
{
    var caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    var counter = 0;

    while (proc != null && proc.MainWindowHandle.ToInt32() == 0 && counter < 30)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        counter++;
    }

    var AppPath = @"C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe";
    caps.SetCapability("appTopLevelWindow", proc?.MainWindowHandle.ToInt64().ToString("x"));
    caps.SetCapability("ms:experimental-webdriver", true);
    caps.SetCapability("app", AppPath);


    var urlWithPort = WinappServerUrl + selectedPort;
    var url = new Uri(urlWithPort);
    var driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(url, caps, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    return driver;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception($"Failed in SetupWinAppDriver. Url={WinappServerUrl + selectedPort}, Exception = {ex}");
}
```

In above code, `var driver = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(url, caps, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));` this line throws after successfull up of Winappdriver and the Notepad.

Error is `System.InvalidOperationException: 'An unknown error occurred in the remote end while processing the command.'`

Tried enabling developer mode.
Tried running winappdriver in Administrator mode.

Comment: Please describe a scenario that you want to automate: do you want to start a notepad or attach it to an existing one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach to the existing process then try to remove the next lines:

- using ""ms:experimental-webdriver" param is not stable
- "app" need only if you want to run app by WinAppDriver

```cs
caps.SetCapability("ms:experimental-webdriver", true);
caps.SetCapability("app", AppPath);
```

If you want to run the app and create a session then remove:

```cs
caps.SetCapability("appTopLevelWindow", proc?.MainWindowHandle.ToInt64().ToString("x"));
caps.SetCapability("ms:experimental-webdriver", true);
```